# Moving data to lower sectors on an SSD without defragging

Tags: ssd, defragment

I bought an Intel SSD drive a while back and now I want to dual-boot with it. But for some reason there are sectors near the end of the drive filled and I can’t seem to find a way to remove the data so that I can safely shrink the partition.

I know I have sectors near the end full because I am using Defraggler to analyze my drive (not to defrag it). I can see what files need to be moved/deleted but short of actually deleting some drivers and/or other necessary files, I am completely stuck. This the diskmap:

[image]

I am only able to shave off that last 1.72GB of space from the drive which isn’t even enough for the most minimal Linux install.

Comment: You do understand moving these file will decrease the lifespan of your SSD hdd right?

Comment: Copy these files instead of moving them and then delete the originals

Answer (score 0):

Many tools (even Windows' disk manager) can resize partitions no matter where in the partitions the files are. They will just move the files like a defragment software would. If Windows can't do it online, it's probably because the sectors are system files being used. In this case you can always run GParted from a Linux LiveCD or use something like Paragon Partiton Manager that can resize partitions during start up.

Comment: @Ramhound Did you even read the question? "... I can’t seem to find a way to remove the data so that I can safely shrink the partition." This is the second sentence!! It's not all about the pretty pictures you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just cut some sectors from a formatted partition in the partition table with the likes of `fdisk` and call it a day, regardless of where the data is physically on it. You need to also resize the filesystem that's on it (i.e. edit its metadata).

So, unless you feel like wading through [NTFS metadata](http://ntfs.com/ntfs_basics.htm) by hand, use a partition manager to resize the partition like normal people do. A decent resizer won't move data around more than is really needed.

You *can* move file data around manually with [Windows defrag API](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeffrey_wall/2004/09/13/defrag-api-c-wrappers/), but I can't see how that's different from "defragging" proper. Some more advanced defraggers can even show you which files occupy the specific area and allow you to defrag just them. But you still have to edit FS metadata to resize the FS, so that won't really do what you want to.